# Update javascript object with another object, but only existing keys

Tags: javascript

Is there a function, either in Javascript or Lodash, in which I can "update" one object with values from another object, but **without adding new keys**?

```
var foo = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1 }
var bar = { 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
```

Something like update(foo, bar), overwriting ("updating") any existing keys, but not adding non-existing keys:

```
{ 'a': 0, 'b': 2 }
```

There's almost certainly a similar question like this on StackOverflow, but I've not been able to find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following are some of the ways you could achieve the desired result.

Instead of modifying the original objects, following code snippets create a new object with all the keys of the target object.

#### Using Nullish Coalescing Operator (??)

`Nullish coalescing operator` returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is `null` or `undefined`, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand. For more details on this operator, see [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
var foo = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1 }
var bar = { 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }

function update(target, src) {
  const res = {};
  Object.keys(target)
        .forEach(k => res[k] = (src[k] ?? target[k]));
  return res;
}

console.log(update(foo, bar));
```

#### Using hasOwnPropery() method

`??` operator will fail for properties with `null` or `undefined` values. As an alternative, you could use `hasOwnProperty()` method. For details on this method, see [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```js
var foo = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1 }
var bar = { 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }

function update(target, src) {
  const res = {};
  Object.keys(target)
        .forEach(k => res[k] = (src.hasOwnProperty(k) ? src[k] : target[k]));
  return res;
}

console.log(update(foo, bar));
```

#### Using 'in' operator

You could also use `in` operator to check for property existence in source object but keep in mind that `in` operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain. For details on `in` operator, see [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

```js
var foo = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1 }
var bar = { 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }

function update(target, src) {
  const res = {};
  Object.keys(target)
        .forEach(k => res[k] = (k in src ? src[k] : target[k]));
  return res;
}

console.log(update(foo, bar));
```

Comment: The test for `src[k]` will run into problems with values that evaluate to false such as `false` or `0`. The test should be replaced with `src.hasOwnProperty(k)`

Comment: @JamesMcGuigan right, didn't think of that. Edited...

Comment: `??`  - this will not work if the property is `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @yash yes i know, i mentioned that in the answer and i am in the process of providing an alternative

Comment: This is the best answer so far (although if the lodash one works, there's something to be said for brevity too.)

Comment: I've been doing Javascript for years, but never before encountered the Nullish coalescing operator (??). Thank you for teaching me something new!

Comment: Here is how you `_.mapValues()` without lodash as a oneliner:

`Object.fromEntries( Object.entries(foo).map(([key, value]) => [key, key in bar ? bar[key] : foo[key]] ) )`

Answer (score 3):

```
var foo = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1 }
var bar = { 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
```

This could also be written slightly more concisely using lodash.

`_.assign` prefers the values in bar

```
_.assign({}, foo, _.pick(bar, _.keys(foo)))
{a: 0, b: 2}
```

`_.defaults` prefers the values in foo

```
_.defaults({}, foo, _.pick(bar, _.keys(foo)))
{a: 0, b: 1}
```

Or extending on from @Yousaf's answer, this could also be done in pure ES6 functional style as a one-liner without needing to create an intermediate object:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(foo)
  .map(([key, value]) => [
    key, 
    key in bar ? bar[key] : foo[key]
  ]) 
);
```

Comment: Is `{a: 0, b: 1}` the output? (OP was looking for a way to get `{a: 0, b: 2}`.)

Comment: Opps (edited). I was getting mixed up between _.assign + _.defaults.

Comment: This is a very nice (and working) method, esp. when already using Lodash.

Answer (score 1):

this should do it:

```
var foo = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1 }
var bar = { 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
Object.entries(bar).forEach( ([key, val]) => { if(foo.hasOwnProperty(key)){ foo[key] = val } })
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple easy and generic solution without using any library :

```js
var foo = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1 }
var bar = { 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }


function updateObject(firstObj, secondObj){

   Object.keys(firstObj).forEach(key => {
 if(secondObj.hasOwnProperty(key)){ 
    firstObj[key]=secondObj[key];    
   }})

  return firstObj;
}

console.log(updateObject(foo,bar));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern, and this is how I have been doing it. I think that it is very clear, but might be slower in some circumstances:

```js
var foo = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1 }
var bar = { 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
Object.keys(foo).map(key => {
  if (key in bar) {
    foo[key] = bar[key]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here it is with `reduce`:

```js
let foo = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1 }
const bar = { 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }

foo = Object.keys(bar).reduce((foo, key) => {
  if(foo[key] != null){ foo[key] = bar[key]; }
  return foo;
}, foo);

console.log(foo);
```

(This assumes no value in foo is explicitly set to `null` or `undefined`, but allows for all other falsy values.)